# How to dynamically modify Android layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I will be developing one android application. In this app I want to generate xml layout dynamically. After login to the app, server will send xml template with description of controls including different attribute description(validations on each control,maxlength,size of the control etc.), which means there will be no predefined xml layout.

My plan is, from downloaded xml template I will create a xml layout and store that xml in sqlite database. When user clicks on a record I want show this dynamically created form to the user.

Is it possible to modify xml layout(like setting innerxml)?

Comment: use html page to load your dynamical view from server.

Comment: web service is just sending a template xml.After login and downloading this templates,the app also should work in offline

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView = inflater.inflate(myXmlPullParser, null);

setContentView(myView);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [View documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29):

> **Important** For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.

**You can't** inflate layout if it is not inside layout res directory.

Comment: there will be one layout file in res dirctory.Is it possible to dynamically change the innerxml(replace with newly created layout) of that layout file???

Comment: you need to inflate the _innerxml_ first. To do that, you need `LayoutInflater.inflate()`. However, this method doesn't accept dynamically loaded. It must be from `res` folder. My conclusion is: You still can't do that.

Comment: @user922834 "Is it possible to dynamically change the innerxml(replace with newly created layout) of that layout file???" - No! Because it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.take one xml layout with only linear layout and in the onCreate access the layout with id and create all the views programatically and add to the linear layout as subviews and later set that xml layout as setContentView.
later you want to add more view after View Created you can run UI thread and add the views.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than creating xml dynamically you should be looking at creating the views you want programatically , 
If its an advanced view you should do as TheWAlkingCube suggested, inflate a xml view dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support your way of working entirely, but you can build up your own layout dynamically.

Create your own *TemplateBuilder*-class. This class will retrieve a layout file from your server (and possible save it in your database). The XML file can be read out and you can add each defined item at runtime. As said before, this is not the conventional way you should work in Android, but it will be your best option.

If you have certain ViewGroups or layouts which will be used in the layouts more often, you can define them as XML files in your **res**-folder and inflate them when needed. Creating predefined *layout-blocks* you can inflate whenever you want and literally build up your custom layout.

For an example for adding view at runtime you can visit the link below:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on doing it this way, you have to parse the xml file received, in your program and add each view of the xml layout programmatically based on how it is requested in the file received