# Can we change view's height / width defined in xml?

Tags: android, view

I have some view defined in my layout xml. e.g.

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/viewScanProgressWheel"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/pbHeight"/>
```

Now, later at any point in time, can I change the height or width of the view, like changing the value in dimens or using some custom attributes?

P.S. I want the values to be changed in xml, not just on UI. So that all the calculations need not be done everytime through java side.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml
Use RelativeLayoutParams / LinearLayoutParams, it must be like the parent view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202474/how-to-dynamically-modify-android-layout-xml

Answer (score 0):

you mean changing the value of dimens in dimen.xml?
i think you can't,
but you can change the width/height etc programatically using [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

```
yourView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
```

do take note, that you must assign the LayoutParam from the package of the view's parent
ex:
your view is a child of LinearLayout, make sure it's LinearLayout.LayoutParams etc, to avoid exceptions
check the reference for more parameters in different LayoutParams by its type of ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

Try this `yourView.getLaoutParams().heigth = x; or yourView.getLaoutParams().width = x;`, and depending when are you calling it you may have to make `yourView.requestLayout();` before

Answer (score 0):

You can always change layout size programmatically using:

```
view.layout(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
```